# Перемещение элементов при скроллинге определённого блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

необходимо реализовать перемещение блоков из "пустоты" на свои места при скроллинге.

Пример правильно собранных блоков:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/35rdx60s/15/
```

```
.main-block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink;
}
.first-stroke {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
.second-stroke {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}
.size {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.block-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.block-orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.block-green {
  background-color: green;
}
.block-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.block-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.block-brown {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

При появлении главного блока в области видимости экрана при скроллинге все 6 элементов встают на свои места.
Как это можно реализовать? хелп пожалуйста...

Comment: Пример: https://www.apple.com/iphone-12-pro/
Блок: "scroll-container"

Comment: Отлавливаете перемещение через https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API и добавляете нужный класс
https://animate.style/